# Use Javascript API in a Java program

Tags: javascript, java, import

I was looking to add data to my program based off of the steam market API that I have found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csgo-market#getsingleknifeprice-knife-skin-wear-stattrak-callback) but I am unsure how to use this data as I believe it is in JavaScript. Is it possible to do so or is this not do-able?

Comment: Maybe the data is in JSON format (there is no 'javascript' data format)

Comment: @Jochen_Bedersdorfer yeh I had a feeling I would just sound dumb. I have no idea what else to call it. My question is CAN I use that in java or is that not possible?

Comment: [how to parse json in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

In Automatical way,

When you get json data from steam api in js/web page, you could pass the data using ajax to java web application controller by RESTful API to comsume/handle that data in java program. You could search "java spring web application" for your starting point

http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html#step1.8

In manual way,

You could just copy the result json string into java normal program to transform into Map/List object by some parsing function or library(e.g. gson) for further computation.

[java code to convert json into text in key value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823746/java-code-to-convert-json-into-text-in-key-value-pair/)